# Understanding regexes: r'(.*)\1' vs r'(.*)' vs r'(.)\1*'

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In these Python examples, why does:

`>>> sub(r'(.)\1*', lambda m: str(m.group()*3)+'-', 'abc')`

outputs

`'aaa-bbb-ccc-'`

and

`>>> sub(r'.*', lambda m: str(m.group()*3)+'-', 'abc')`

`'abcabcabc--'`

and:

`>>> sub(r'(.*)\1', lambda m: str(m.group()*3)+'-', 'abc')`

`'-a-b-c-'`

Why don't the first or last match the whole string? (and pass it as a group).

Why does the second one add two '-' at the end?

Answer (score 3):

For #1, `\1` matches what the group *actually* matched, not what it *could have matched*, which is I suspect the root of your confusion. The `.` resolves to a specific character (e.g. `a`), then the `\1*` resolves to zero or more `a`s, not zero or more "any characters". Since no character is repeated, you only match a single character at a time.

In #3, you match only empty strings, because there are no longer strings that repeat in the input, so `\1` only applies when `(.*)` captured nothing (the empty string), which it does once at the beginning, end, and in-between each character in the input.

Both of the above are pretty straightforward if you know regex syntax. But #2 is the weird one, in that it matches the whole string (`.*` captures the whole thing), then, in an arguably incorrect follow-on, matches the "following" empty string, and replaces each, leading to two hyphens.

Really, the short answer to your entire question is "`*` is an unsafe/non-intuitive quantifier to start with, and applying it to `.` makes it worse". Try to use `+` where at all possible, as it avoids these "match nothing" weirdo cases.